# Is there a way to automatically update installed programs?

Tags: updates, automatic

I have enabled automatic system updates, but I also have non-system applications installed (like Google Chrome, Atom, Sublime Text, Spotify, etc.). Is there a way to include these in the automatic updating process or is there another way to ensure I always run the latest version of these programs?

Comment: If you install applications from apt repositories, the system will check updates for them as well. Chrome will do for sure.

Comment: *Keeping things short and simple*. "Automatic Updates" totally depends on the factor how you installed that particular app. APT and Snap takes care of keeping the application up-to-date. But if you installed some `.deb` file or using binary file then automatic update is not ensured. (Applications like Google Chrome are exception since they perform some extra actions)

Answer (score 2):

The system checks for updates by searching on all the servers that are listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and on all the servers that have been added by other software installers or manually, in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder in the form of `software-name.list` files.

If the software you've installed has added entries in the places mentioned above, then yes, the system will check for updates for that software too.

For example, **Google Chrome** and **Spotify** do add update servers when you install them normally.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's an example** of how to add Google Chrome (deb) to Unattended Upgrades. This WON'T work for Snaps and other non-deb software. We're assuming that you already know how to safely edit a settings file.

**1) You need to know the Source of the package.**

All your sources should be located in either `/etc/apt/sources.list` or within `etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Find the source that provides your package.

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
google-chrome-stable.list
google-chrome-stable.list.distUpgrade
```

Open the .list file to see the URL on the bottom line

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

We will use a slightly changed version of that URL in the next step.

**2) You need to know the Origin Field for the Source.**

The Origin field is hidden inside apt's working files, but is easy to find:

```
$ grep Origin /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release
Origin: Google LLC
```

**3) Add the Origin to your Unattended Upgrades settings**

The relevant Unattended Upgrades settings are near the top of the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. It looks like this for most folks:

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
//
// Note that in Ubuntu security updates may pull in new dependencies
// from non-security sources (e.g. chromium). By allowing the release
// pocket these get automatically pulled in.
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        // Extended Security Maintenance; doesn't necessarily exist for
        // every release and this system may not have it installed, but if
        // available, the policy for updates is such that unattended-upgrades
        // should also install from here by default.
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

Add the new Origin anywhere in the `Allowed-Origins { }` field. Here's an example adding it at the bottom:

```
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
        "Google LLC:stable";
};
```

**4) Test it**

Verify that the change works by running `unattended upgrades`, and then checking the u-u logs in /var/log/unattended-upgrades. If there is an error, and you cannot figure out your mistake, then undo the change.

Security updates are important - DON'T leave them broken if you make a mistake.