# Automate Updates and Upgrade?

Tags: apt, package-management, sudo, automatic

Is there a way to automate updates and upgrades with apt or some other package manager:
Instead of writing these commands below:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-dist upgrade.

I mean like the system updates or upgrades automatically ever there are some have changed?

Answer (score 3):

A stock Ubuntu system *already* automatically updates/upgrades. These features are already included with a normal Ubuntu install.

- Snapd checks for snap packages updates four times each day, and silently downloads and installs any that are discovered. This is a key feature of Snaps, and is how the all-Snap Ubuntu Core stays up completely up to date automatically. See https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date for how to edit the frequency and other settings.
- The system runs `apt update` daily on a timer. The timer runs at a random time each day to avoid hammering the mirrors. Example of how to see it:

  ```
  $ systemctl list-timers apt-daily
  NEXT                        LEFT    LAST                        PASSED  UNIT            ACTIVATES
  Thu 2021-04-15 13:49:38 CDT 6h left Wed 2021-04-14 20:50:52 CDT 10h ago apt-daily.timer apt-daily.service
  ```
- The system runs `apt upgrade` *for security upgrades only* daily on a timer (Unattended Upgrades). Example of how to see it:

  ```
  $ systemctl list-timers apt-daily-upgrade
  NEXT                        LEFT     LAST                        PASSED    UNIT                    ACTIVATES                
  Fri 2021-04-16 06:41:09 CDT 22h left Thu 2021-04-15 07:24:53 CDT 24min ago apt-daily-upgrade.timer apt-daily-upgrade.service
  ```

  You can easily add the -updates pocket of the Ubuntu repositories (bugfixes and non-security upgrades) by editing the config file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. Simply uncomment the appropriate line of the file. Other pockets of the Ubuntu repositories (-proposed, -backports) are not recommended due to the risk of automatically installing a package that breaks your system.

  It's possible to add non-Ubuntu deb sources (like Chrome) to the same automatic upgrade config ([here's how](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121188/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-installed-programs)), but it's not recommended. Many third-party sources do not update in sync with Ubuntu, causing unexpected apt conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Please consult the excellent resource: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates and feel free to choose any of the suggested methods to automate the updates:

- Use the GNOME Update Manager
- Use the unattended-upgrades package
- Use cron-apt
- Write your own cron script that calls aptitude

My favorite way to update the Ubuntu machines is by using the "unattended-upgrades" package: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low unattended-upgrades`, it has a quick interactive dialog which will create the file: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` with these two lines:

`APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";`

`APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";`

Please consult the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, it has a lot of goodies, like list of packages denied upgrade, automatic removal of unused packages, automatic reboot after upgrade (even at specific time) and you can decide what other options you may want use for the updates.
Happy updating!!

Comment: I like to see what updated, just to know if I have an issue whether it was from an update. So I run a script that does updata & some housecleaning of old logs & caches. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2459453
Simple clean script similar to what I created for myself. 
https://github.com/jabarihunt/Ubuntu-Cleanup-Script/blob/master/clean.sh

Comment: To see what was updated, the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` has a section where we can set our emails: `Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "your-email@hostin.com";` an entry when to send the email report: `Unattended-Upgrade::MailReport "on-change" (or: "always", "only-on-error");` and an entry where we can set the report verbosity level, like this: `Unattended-Upgrade::Verbose "true"`

Answer (score 2):

Edit the configuration file (here with nano – replace with any other text editor):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

The beginning of the configuration file should look like this:
[follow image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlRI9.png)

Anything after a double slash “//” is a comment and has no effect. To “enable” a line, remove  the double slash at the beginning of the line (replace with nothing or with spaces to keep alignment).

The most important: uncomment the “updates” line by deleting the two slashes at the beginning of it:

```
${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates
```

Recommended: remove unused kernel packages and dependencies and make sure the system automatically reboots if needed by uncommenting and adapting the following lines:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";  // check for semicolon in Ubuntu 18.04

Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";

Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";

Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:38";
```

To save your changes in nano, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. To quit, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.